# O que são e como funcionam as seguintes declarações em páginas Web Forms: <% %>, <%# %> e <%: %>

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Não sei o que são, nem como chamá-las. São tags, declarações? O que são?

Na prática, percebi algumas características.

1. `<% %>`
   Essa declaração aceita código executável, mas não retorna nada para a página web.
2. `<%# %>`
   Essa declaração também aceita código executável, mas aparentemente se limita a uma expressão e não executa métodos sem retorno. Também não retorna nada para a página web.
3. `<%: %>`
   Essa declaração é idêntica a declaração acima, porém tem seu valor retornado para a página web.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## <% %>

> Essa declaração aceita código executável, mas não retorna nada para a página web.

Depende. Na verdade não é bem isso que você colocou.

Essa é a marcação herdada do ASP Clássico. Ela simplesmente executa alguma instrução imperativa, não necessariamente escrevendo em HTML.

Agora, eu posso perfeitamente escrever no HTML usando da seguinte forma:

```
<% Response.Write("Estou escrevendo no HTML!"); %>
```

## <%# %>

> Essa declaração também aceita código executável, mas aparentemente se limita a uma expressão e não executa métodos sem retorno. Também não retorna nada para a página web.

Não é bem isso. Essa declaração serve pra você realizar amarrações de dados (*binding*) dentro de outra tag ASP.NET. Por exemplo:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Coluna")  %>' Width="70" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Neste caso, `<%# Eval("Coluna") %>` faz a amarração de dados para `<asp:Image>`.

## <%: %>

> Essa declaração é idêntica a declaração acima, porém tem seu valor retornado para a página web.

Na verdade `<%: %>` é equivalente a `<%= %>`, [com o adicional de realizar a codificação de caracteres adequada para o HTML](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:uf877WcyF6cJ:weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2+&cd=1&hl=pt-BR&ct=clnk&gl=br).

[Há outras notações não mencionadas na pergunta que podem ser encontradas aqui](http://weblogs.asp.net/ahmedmoosa/embedded-code-and-inline-server-tags).